# What is Meta exactly?

Tags: support, meta

I'm just wondering exactly what meta is used for. What questions should be asked in it?

When you ask a question in meta, you have to tag either "bug, feature-request, discussion, or support".
So does that mean that meta is for improving the gaming stackexchange site?

If you could tell me about it or direct me to somewhere that I can find out more, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think the meta's [About page](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/about) summarizes it pretty well; also take a look at meta's [FAQ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq). In short, Arqade is a site for asking and answering questions about video games, and Meta Arqade is a site for asking and answering questions about the Arqade site.

Comment: This is pretty much it. I'd add however, that some of the rules are a bit more... fast and loose on meta -  particularly those regarding subjectivity and 'discussion' oriented questions. Where those are to be avoided on Arqade, on Meta, they're encouraged -  so long as they're about Arqade, the Stack Exchange Engine, the Community here, or something similar, and not about your awesome theory for what the ending of Mass Effect *really* means.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz true dat. We should also probably mention that votes mean something else on meta than on the main site: here on meta it's okay to vote on things based on whether or not you *agree* with them, even if they are otherwise of high quality and show research effort.